# Bootstrap modal - prevent javascript from positioning

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying the following:

I'm using a plugin, that makes a tour for the page, therefore it has its self defined styles, creating a box and a arrow. Now I tried to restlye that, to use bootstrap modal instead.

What I have now is the following:

```
this._annoElem = $("<div class='tour-modal modal" + this.className + "'>\n<div class='modal-dialog'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'><button type='button' ng-click='hideAnno();' class='close btn btn-secondary btn btn-icon-only' aria-label='Close'>Close</button> </div> <div class='anno-arrow'></div></div></div>\n</div>");

this._annoElem.find('.modal-content').append("<div class='modal-body'>" + this.contentElem() + "</div>").append(this.buttonsElem());

return this._annoElem;
```

And, what should I say, the modal/box itself looks as it should, so the "styling" is as it should, but I have big problems with positioning. The problem seems to be, that bootstrap sets some value for `top` in javascript, so this is somehow messing everything up. Also I'm wondering with type of `position` I need, as `position:relative` seems to move my elements. Maybe somebody can help me here?

Btw:[thats](http://iamdanfox.github.io/anno.js/) the plugin I'm using and the original code of `this._annoElem` looks the following:

```
this._annoElem = $("<div class='anno anno-hidden " + this.className + "'>\n<div class='anno-inner'>  <div class='anno-arrow'></div>  </div>\n</div>");

this._annoElem.find('.anno-inner').append(this.contentElem()).append(this.buttonsElem());

return this._annoElem;
```

so I actually only added all modal tags and removed the tags from anno.

Comment: FYI : http://bootstraptour.com/

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Thanks for the tip, but I knew that one, but anno.js has some benefits for me, so I prefer it.

Comment: Have you tried the default *position*, which is absolute?

Comment: If you view the [Anno.JS documentation](http://iamdanfox.github.io/anno.js/docco/anno.html) the *emphasiseTarget:* method sets the *$target* css property of *position* to *absolute*.  FYI - the *relative* value of *position* will lay out the elements as if the element were still in its normal flow of the document.  Where as absolute elements are taken out of flow.

Comment: @OverflowStack position absolute at least doesn't seem to move my element, but the positioning is still not correct (so it's either way to high (in relation to the highlighted element) or it appears on the highlighted element, but not as it should...

Comment: Just for clarification, we are now talking about the the built in ***Anno.js*** *positioning property*  as opposed to the ***css*** *positioning property*.  With that being said, you can omit the *position* attribute, leaving it up to a **best guess** scenario or you can manually supply the values *(eg: top, left, bottom, right, center-top, center-left etc...)* to get the desired effect.

Comment: @OverflowStack Yes we're talking about the positioning of Anno.js, or say I want to use the auto positioning of Anno.js, but theres the problem that bootstrap seems to override some of the position-properties that anno sets, because I added the modal classes....

Comment: Then you can manually set the ***Anno.js*** *positioning* when setting up your *modal*, for example    ***position: { top: 'auto', left: '100px' }***.

Comment: @OverflowStack this at least improved appearence, just one time it's interestingly in the highlighted area and not underneath or over it.... Also I'm wondering that everything is very very delayed, so for maybe about half a second, you can see two of the "anno boxes" at once, so it takes hardly long. Do you know why this could be the case? (As in the "normal" anno, this is working fine.)

Comment: Where is your css styling in relation to your Anno.js file?

Comment: As far as loading latency, there could be a number of reasons for delays.  I would start by loading your **URL** into an analyzer such as *[Google PageSpeed Analyzer](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)*.  This will give you some suggestions on what needs to be improved.  In the meantime, I would utilize a ***CDN (content delivery network)*** to cache the files to the browser.  Here is a *[Bootstrap CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)* and a *[jQuery CDN](https://code.jquery.com/)*.

Comment: @OverflowStack You mean, where my css-file is compared to the anno.js/anno.css file? Anno is in a `node_modules` folder and my css styling is in a css file thats in the same folder as my definitions (of the javascript i posted above)
Depending the latency, is there not maybe I could change in css to make things smoother, maybe something like here (http://introjs.com/) would be posssible, to the transitions are smoother (and it's not "lagging" any more)?

Comment: @OverflowStack also a CDN might be interesting, but not currently, because I currently run everything locally for testing, so I don't think this (at least currently) influences my timing.